# Bootcamping a Mac. Got windows installed correctly but now it cant see the USB that Bootcamp had me make with all the Mac drivers

Tags: bootcamp, usb, windows

Pretty much as title says.  Went through Bootcamp Assistant, created the USB with Mac versions of the Windows drivers, and installed Windows.  Can successfully dual boot, however, none of my devices work.  When I plug in the USB to install those drivers, Windows doesn't recognize it.  Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a problem with the USB3 drivers. You can download the latest bootcamp drivers on [Apple's website](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1638?viewlocale=en_US).

Comment: Okay downloaded and hit setup.exe on the BootCamp folder of the zip.  Error was `Boot Camp x64 is unsupported on this computer model` Windows installation is Win 7 x64 ultimate and Mac is a Macbook 10.8.5

Answer (score 2):

I see your problem. You should try to install the latest drivers for BOOTCAMP. If this doesn't fix it, there's a problem with your USB3 Drivers.

Install here : http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1638

Try this too : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj945423.aspx

This should help :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest update for bootcamp and the drivers [Click here.](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1638)

The link I provided, is update 5, try it out.